# VBScript: Invalid Character 800A0408 compilation error in Line 1 Char 1

Tags: scripting

Hello so im new at doing this and it says this [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s5SW.png  and here is the script

````
do
wscript.sleep 100
wshshell.sendkeys “{CAPSLOCK}”
wshshell.sendkeys “{NUMLOCK}”
wshshell.sendkeys “{SCROLLLOCK}”
loop```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have smart quotes in your script. Try to avoid them while coding.

Change them to straight quotes:

```
Debug.Print "Start"

Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ctr = 1
Do
   Debug.Print "Loop " & ctr
   wscript.Sleep 1000  ' one second
   wshshell.SendKeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
   wshshell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
   wshshell.SendKeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
   ctr = ctr + 1
Loop
```

Comment: sorry my code wasnt fully put on Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”)
do
wscript.sleep 100
wshshell.sendkeys “{CAPSLOCK}”
wshshell.sendkeys “{NUMLOCK}”
wshshell.sendkeys “{SCROLLLOCK}”
loop

Comment: Code updated. You can remove the Debug statements. I used them for testing.